# Adding a course to one of 8 periods

Tags: java, beginner

I have this rather ghastly `if` statement and I'm sure there is a way to condense it, but I don't really know how.  I was told a `case` statement would work but I've never used a `case` statement and I'm not sure.

```
public void add(int p, Course c)
{
    if (p == 1){
    if (course1.isFree() == true) {
        course1 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 2){
        if (course2.isFree() == true) {
        course2 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 3){
        if (course3.isFree() == true) {
        course3 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 4){
        if (course4.isFree() == true) {
        course4 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 5){
        if (course5.isFree() == true) {
        course5 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 6){
        if (course6.isFree() == true) {
        course6 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 7){
        if (course7.isFree() == true) {
        course7 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    } else if (p == 8){
        if (course8.isFree() == true) {
        course8 = c;
        System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
    }
    }

    totalcredits();
}
```

Comment: I would start by fixing the indentation, to be sure what you are dealing with,

Answer (score 34):

> ```
>     if (course3.isFree() == true) {
>     course3 = c;
>     System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
> } else {
>     System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
> }
>
> ...
>
> } else if (p == 8){
>     if (course8.isFree() == true) {
>     course8 = c;
>     System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
> } else {
>     System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
> }
> ```

Good thing there aren't 20.. 200... 2,000... 20,000 courses!

This code needs to *DRY* a bit. **Don't repeat yourself.™**

Programming is about *abstractions* - this code need one here, badly: there should be a concept of a *bunch of courses* in your program.

Then it would be possible to only write the block once. Given `courses` is an *array of <s>courses</s> `Course`*... of course:

```
public void add(int period, Course course) {
|
|---if (courses[period].isFree()) {
|   |
|   |---courses[period] = course; 
|   |---System.out.println("Course " + course + "added to period " + period +".\n");
|   |
|---} else {
|   |
|   |---System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
|---}
|
}
```

Notice the position of the scope-closing braces: by lining them up with the indentation of the line that opened the scope, you make the code much easier to follow, and avoid this:

> ```
>     }
>     }
> ```

Also notice the names I've used. Avoid single-letter identifiers, like `p` and `c`. Code is much easier to read when it's... readable.

---

This is too verbose:

> ```
> if (course.isFree() == true) {
> ```

Since `course.isFree()` obviously returns a Boolean value, the Boolean value itself can serve as the expression of the condition, which means you don't need to compare it to `true`:

```
if (course.isFree()) {
```

Answer (score 12):

@Mat's Mug has a pretty good answer, and I'll like to go one step further with a couple more questions:

1. What are `course1...course8`? Global variables? Any reasons why they are not a `Collection` of courses?
2. What exactly is the relationship between `p`, `c` and `course1...course8`? Is `p` some form of user input indicating the desired period the course `c` should go to, to be set for one of `course<n>`? The reason why I ask this is because clearly you are only checking whether `course<n>` is free for period `<n>`.
3. How is calling `totalcredits()` related to adding a course to one of 8 periods?

If you can post a follow-up question by answering some of the above (say with more code from other parts), then I think there's a lot more that we can help you to improve on.

edit:

Let's attempt to break down the actions into some steps.

1. We need to get the `course` for the specified `period` value, so we may have something like this:

   ```
   private Course getCourse(int period) {
       return courses.get(period - 1); // assuming period is not zero-based
   }
   ```
2. We can now call `getCourse(period)` inside your `add` method:

   ```
   public final void add(int period, final Course course) {
       final Course selectedCourse = getCourse(period);
       if (selectedCourse.isFree()) {
           // do something about course
           // print success
       } else {
           // print failure
       }
   }
   ```
3. What does it mean to set `course<n>` to the `course` input? Wouldn't you need to do something like `setFree(false)` too to indicate the course is 'no longer free'? This is why I am suggesting that you re-evaluate the logic you require for adding a course to a period and marking that period/course as occupied. You may want to do something like the following:

   ```
   if (selectedCourse.isFree()) {
       selectedCourse.copyFrom(course); // maybe some checks on 'free' will be done too
   }
   ```

Comment: To be honest, most of the things done in this are simply to meet the requirements of my AP-comp sci class... So as long as it works its okay with me. He wanted us to do it this way so I did, I would have wanted an array. Course 1-8 are actually objects and I used a constructor to build them, its a rather rudimentary system, and they're are far more effective ways to do so.

Comment: Hmms, if you still prefer `course1...course8`, maybe you can still consider my idea of a separate `getCourse()` method to hide the logic of picking the `course` for the specified `period` from your actual `add` method, in case you can and want to change that (to an array/`Collection`) in the future. This will drastically simplify your code inside the `add` method.

Comment: @RexPRGMER If someone in charge wants something that strange, you should follow. But don't interpret it too literally, they want to be able to access `course1`, etc., so provide such an interface, but ever think about coding everything 8 times. Pack all courses into an array/list ad work with it. Everywhere.

Answer (score 11):

Since you are testing equality for integer you use switch instead of multiple if-else if.

```
switch(p){
    case 1:
       break;
    case 2:
       break;

}
```

The code above is equivalent to

```
if(p == 1){

}
else if(p == 2){

}
```

You can use the shorthand `if` using the operator `?` for simple if-else. Thus, your code will look something like this:

```
public void add(int p, Course c){
    Course currentCourse;
    switch(p){
     case 1:
           //if course1.isFree, currentCourse is c, else currentCourse is course1
           currentCourse = course1.isFree() ? c : course1;
           break;
     case 2:
           currentCourse = course2.isFree() ? c : course2;
           break;

     <add more cases here>
     }

     //display appropriate message
     if(currentCourse.equals(c)){
         System.out.println("Course " + c + "added to period " + p +".\n");
     }else{
         System.out.println("Unable to add class to a nonfree period.");
     }
}
```